# How do you pass a Container.DataItem as a parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using a repeater control and I'm trying to pass a parameter as such:

```
<%# SomeFunction( DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id") ) %>
```

It's basically calling:

```
public string SomeFunction(long id) {

    return "Hello";        

}
```

I'm not able to achieve this as I get an error:

error CS1502: The best overloaded method match ... SomeFunction(long id) ... has some invalid arguments.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to cast the result to a long, so:

```
<%# SomeFunction( (long)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id") ) %>
```

The alternative is to do something like this:

```
<%# SomeFunction(Container.DataItem) %>
```

and...

```
public string SomeFunction(object dataItem) {
    var typedDataItem = (TYPED_DATA_ITEM_TYPE)dataItem;

    // DO STUFF HERE WITH THE TYPED DATA ITEM

    return "Hello";        

}
```

This at least allows you to work with multiple values from the data item (DataRows etc).

Answer (score 2):

I think you should cast the DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id") as long.

Answer (score 1):

I used this with success. The data source is a List collection.

```
OnClientClick='<%# "return myFunction(\""+ Container.DataItem + "\");" %>'
```

and the javascript function...

```
function myFunction(imgPath)
{
    alert(imgPath);
}
```