# How can i use foreach in Container.DataItem?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can i use it in Repeater ItemTemplate ?

```
foreach(string tag in Eval("etiketler"))
{
    Response.Write("<a href='#'>"+tag+"</a");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no way to do it in this format. you should send **Dataitem** to a static method and then you should return string that contains your markup..

```
public static string GetMarkup(object dataItem)
{
    var tags = DataBinder.Eval(dataItem, "etiketler"); // depend on etiketler type

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach(string tag in tags) 
    { 
        sb.Append("<a href='#'>"+tag+"</a"); 
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

use this method like this:

```
<%# GetMarkup(Container.DataItem) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<%#` is not made to use `foreach` with it, neither `if` or other language keywords. It's mainly done to databinding.

But you can :

- Do it in codebehind with the _ItemDataBound event of the repeater (hugely recommanded for complex processings/formatting).
  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
- Call a method of the page which takes in parameter the DataItem and creates the data you want.  See [How do you pass a Container.DataItem as a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287358/how-do-you-pass-a-container-dataitem-as-a-parameter) for example

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can also use nested repeaters in ASP.NET

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rpt1">
  <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID ="rpt2" DataSource='<%# Eval("etiketler") %>'>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("tag") %>
     </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```